# How can you get the sub-projects of an IMS through the Project Server 2016 REST API?

Tags: rest, project-server, ms-project

I know that in the `ProjectServer` REST API, there is a property on Task objects called `IsSubProject`.  So I can get all the summary tasks that represent sub projects within a master schedule by this query:

```
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('project-id-here')/Tasks?$filter=IsSubProject eq true
```

But, then I can't figure out how to get the Project objects for those sub-projects.  I can't do a query of all projects and filter by name, because the summary task name can be different than the actual file name/project name of the Project.  And the Task Id does not match the Project Id.

I can get the corresponding Task objects from the `ProjectData` service, but there doesn't seem to be any additional information linking it to the actual sub-project Project. (The `ProjectData` tasks don't even have `IsSubProject`.)

How can I get to the sub-project's Projects?